# AngularJS data not siplay also no error in console

Tags: angularjs

Here is code....(included file empDetails.php is fine)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcesV.jpg)

Comment: explain briefly

Comment: debug the application and verify it you are getting data in $scope.details?

Comment: thanks @BalajiM can you process or steps for debug ... actually i am new..

Comment: for @Manikandan .... i build a application simple for retrieving data from database using AngularJS.. so there is code in image attachment ...in this code is proper execute .. no error in console... but data are also not display so please help for this issue...

Comment: put your code in plunkr or else some other

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't declare ng-app="myApp" in the root of your html page

Comment: I can't see it. There's only ng-controller attribute, not ng-app

Comment: i upload a cropped image...also mention in comment i.e. not display in mage